# FirebaseUI Web email verification and Right side of login cut off

Tags: javascript, email, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

So I am trying to create a user login system (for now with Google and email/password), and using Firebase UI to do so. However I've been having a few problems. At first, I got this code to work, but for some reason, even after trying new projects, browsers, and emails, it no longer works. If anyone has any idea about a possible fix/what I am doing wrong, that would be much appreciated.

```
var uiConfig = {
callbacks: {
  signInSuccess: function(currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) {
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified) {
      window.location.href = 'loggedIn.html';
    } else {
      firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
      alert("Check your email to verify your account");
      window.location.href = 'index.html';
    }
    return false;
  }
},
```

My second problem is that for the email verification, the save and submit buttons are cut off on the right side whether on a computer or phone. I don't have any css or js files not in the github tutorial, but this still happens. If anyone knows any possible solutions to either of these that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Google will handle resetting an email password for you, so you don't have to supply any code for that. When you get singInSuccess, currentUser has all the information about the signed you user you need.